# Compile time error while using Java Generic type class

Tags: java, generics

Not able to return to the desired generic type format

**I am using a generic type class**

```
public class GResponse<T> {
   public String msg;
   public String status;
   public T res;
}
```

**and in the below class, I need to return GResponse**

```
public GResponse<User_details> Uname(String username) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User_details.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user_id", username));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("auth_stat", "A"));
    List<User_details> list2 = criteria.list();
    if (list2.size() == 1) {

    }
    return User_details(list2);
   // return loginDao.findByUsername(username);
}
```

but in the above return statement it is giving compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Your return method causes the program to look for a `User_details(List<User_details> list2)` method inside your particular class. Maybe you meant to do `return new User_details(list2);` But from the looks of it you want to accommodate a list of details and then store those in a `GResponse` instance.

Either way a better approach would be:

```
public class GResponse<T> {
  public String msg;
  public String status;
  public T res;

  public void add(T res) {
      this.res = res;
  }
}
.
.
.

GResponse<List<User_details>> completeDetails = new Gresponse<List<User_details>>();
completeDetails.add(list2);

return completeDetails;
```

Also please do include your error messages in your future posts.

Comment: In that case feel free to upvote this answer so people can see it